# What CSS selectors to know for WordPress?

Tags: css

Could anyone tell me what types of CSS selectors available in the main theme of WordPress? because I want to learn CSS and I just want to learn the necessary types for WordPress.

Comment: What do you mean by the **types** of [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html)?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question, overall, for users looking to edit the standard twentythirteen theme, but it really isn't going to help you in the long run. I suggest starting at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) to learn more about theme development, then check out the [List of WP Generated Classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes) to see what WP is creating for you.

If you really just want to learn CSS, do a Google search for CSS tutorials. I'm up voting this only to raise awareness to the generated classes list in the codex.